# td on click doesn't work and get the value

Tags: ajax, get, html-table

I am building searching input. When user type in that input box, I wanna automatically show the closest object that has same words like user type. Looks Like this :

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

function hasil_cari(){
  var hasil = $("#tujuan_cepat").val();
  $.ajax({
   url: "ambildataobjek.php",
   data: "hasil="+hasil,
   cache: true,
   success: function(msg){
    $("#form_hasil_pencarian").html(msg);
    $('.form_hasil_pencarian').show();
   }
  });
 }
 
 
  
 $(document).on('click','.hasil_pencarian',function() {
     alert("this");
     document.getElementById("navigasi_cepat").disabled = false;

 });
```

```html
   
<div id="pencarian">
    <form id="form_navigasi_cepat" name="form_navigasi_cepat" method="POST">
     <input type="text" class="textboxutama"  name="tujuan_cepat" id="tujuan_cepat" onKeyPress="hasil_cari();" placeholder="Alamat Yang dituju" required>
     <input type="text" class="textboxutama" id="lokasi_tersembunyi" name="lokasi_tersembunyi" hidden>
     <button type="submit" class="buttonutama" id="navigasi_cepat" disabled>Rute</button>
     <br>
     <div id="form_hasil_pencarian" class="form_hasil_pencarian" hidden>
     </div>
    </form>
    
    </div>
```

For query, I use ajax. AndThis is file ambildataobjek.php for gettig objek :

```html
<?php

if (isset($_GET['hasil'])){    
    include ("php/connect.php");
 $hasil = $_GET['hasil'];
 $hasil_objek = mysql_query("SELECT w.nama_wisata, l.lat_lokasi, l.lang_lokasi FROM lokasi l, wisata w, jenis j WHERE (w.nama_wisata LIKE '%$hasil%' or j.nama_jenis LIKE '%$hasil%') and w.idjenis_wisata = j.id_jenis and l.id_lokasi=w.idlokasi_wisata");
 while($k = mysql_fetch_array($hasil_objek)){
?>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="tabel_hasil_pencarian">

<?PHP
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class=\"hasil_pencarian\">".$k['nama_wisata']."</td>\n";
  echo "</tr>";
 }    
} 


?>

</table>
```

When I click td from ajax that has shown, I wanna put td value to input with id="tujuan_cepat", but I Can not.
How I get Value from that td?